# Bug after upgrade Magento 2.3.4 to 2.3.5

Tags: magento2, magento2.3.5

My website show a lot bug after upgrade Magento 2.3.4 to Magento 2.3.5, It show like this [image]

I found a temporary solution is turn off an extension Magento_CSP. But I think turn off Magento extension is not good idea.

Thank you for your advice!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I already submitted enhancement request to Magento (https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/28066), but as you thought, to disable Magento_Csp module is the fastest solution.

Other solution is... to set report-uri parameter. You can use https://report-uri.com/ and other similar services.

Comment: Thank you for your help! I think they should let us know it Or turn that extension off when they release Magento 2.3.5.